# nested loop code not working please

Tags: python, loops, nested

```
with open(sys.argv[2]) as f:
     processlist = f.readlines()
     for a in range(0,1):
         process = processlist[a]
         print process
         for b in range(0,3):
             process1 = process.split()
             print process1[b]
```

sys.argy[2 ] files just has 2 sentences

```
Sunday Monday
local owner public
```

I am trying to read once sentence at a time and in each sentence I am trying to access one word at a time.... I am able to get the things i need individually but the loop doesn’t not iterate... it stops after first iteration....

Answer (score 3):

```
with open(sys.argv[2]) as f:
    for line in f: #iterate over each line
        #print("-"*10) just for demo
        for word in line.rstrip().split(): #remove \n then split by space
            print(word)
```

Over your file would produce

```
----------
Sunday
Monday
----------
local
owner
public
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question why the loop doesn't iterate:

```
range(0,1)
```

contains only the element `0`, since [the upper bound is not included in the result](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range). Similarly,

```
range(0,5)
```

would, when viewed as a list, be `[0,1,2,3,4]`.

The correct way to iterate over a file is demonstrated by @HennyH's answer.